# Trouble filling input fields with placeholder data in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Supernoob here.  I have a 'users' table and a 'businesses' table in the database.  Trying to pull the data from the businesses table into the form as a placeholder.  Currently, the fields are blank and I cannot save new input info to the table either.  I need help to accomplish both.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit.blade.php  ($business is defined in User.php below)

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="/business/{{ $business->slug }}/edit" method="post">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('businessname') ? ' has-error' : ' ' }}">
            <label for="businessname" class="control-label col-sm-3">Business Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="businessname" name="businessname" value="{{ old('businessname') ? old('businessname') : $business->businessname }}">
            </div>
            @if ($errors->has('businessname'))
                <div class="help-block">
                    {{ $errors->first('businessname') }}
                </div>
            @endif
            </div>
        </div>   
    </form>
</div>
```

User.php (Business class is defined in Business.php below)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname', 'lastname','email', 'phonenumber','password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function business()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Business::class);
}
}
```

Business.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname', 'lastname','email', 'phonenumber','password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function business()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Business::class);
}
}
```

web.php (the routes are defined in web.php)

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
Route::get('/business/{slug}/edit', 'BusinessProfileController@edit');
Route::put('/business/{slug}/edit', 'BusinessProfileController@update');
});
```

BusinessProfileController.php (here is the controller)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Business;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class BusinessProfileController extends Controller
{

public function edit(Business $business)
{

    return view('business.settings.edit', [
            'business' => $business
        ]);
}

public function update()
{
    \\
}
}
```

Comment: Please display your controller code for store and view form method

Comment: I put the correct file for the BusinessProfileController with the view function.  I'm not sure if I am correctly storing though (or viewing for that matter).